# the probability for exactly two consecutive successs

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, binomial-distribution

Calculate the probability of getting exactly 50 heads and 50 tails after flipping a fair coin 100 times.
for this question we can easily apply the the binomial distribution formula, as $100 \choose 50$  $\frac{1}{2}^{100}$

What if we are asked

Calculate the probability of getting **exactly consecutive** 10 heads or 10 tails after flipping a fair coin 100 times?  would binomial distribution still work. thank you

Comment: Do you mean 50 heads followed by 50 tails? If you really mean 10 heads and 10 tails, you might need to be more specific: are you allowing this to occur more than once in the 100 flips, are you allowing 11 heads followed by 12 tails to count, etc.

Comment: This is not at all clear.  Since $10+10<100$ you can not get "exactly" $10$ heads and $10$ tails in $100$ tosses.  What are you asking?

Comment: When you say exactly 10 heads and 10 tails, do you mean after obtaining 10 heads and then 10 tails in the 100 trials, you then get a head?

Comment: @lulu exactly consecutive.  Doesn't  that mean 11 consecutive wont't count ? 
if that have different meaning, apologize. still improve my english still as well, hope you don't mind

Comment: I'd say the phrasing is very ambiguous.  I could make a guess as to your meaning.  Maybe something like "the longest consecutive streak of Heads has length $10$ and similarly for Tails" but even that isn't clear.  Suppose there are three strings of length $10$ which are all Heads, and one such string that's all Tails.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Regardless of your precise meaning:  this is certainly not a binomial distribution question as the combinatorics behind counting "good" strings dominates the question.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting exactly consecutive 10 heads and 10 tails is $\frac{1}{2}^{20}$.

Then you have to consider that it can happen from zero to five times.
So you have to use the Bernoulli’s Formula to calculate the total probability:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{5} \binom{5}{k}  \left( \frac{1}{2}^{20} \right)^{5}  \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}^{20} \right)^{5-k}$$

Comment: Sorry. I meant
Calculate the probability of getting exactly consecutive 10 heads or 10 tails after flipping a fair coin 100 times? would binomial distribution still work. 
changing " 10 heads and 10 tails" to " 10 heads or 10 tails"
thank you